# Insert a graph with kv lang

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make an APP with 2 screen:

- First screen is a Button
- Second screen shows a graph

When the Button of the first screen is pressed, the second screen appears with the graph. 
I was able to plot the graph with 1 screen only, using matplotlib.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy")
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Sensores(Screen):
    pass

class Grafico(Screen):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

class Menu(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file('sensor.kv')

class sensor(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sensor().run()
```

KIVY

```
Menu:
    Sensores:
    Grafico:

<Sensores>
    name: 'sensores'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Sensor 01"
            on_release:
                root.Grafico()

<Grafico>
    name: 'grafico'
```

I expect to have the graph in the second screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much!
It works now! Follow the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy")
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

plt.plot([1,23,2,4])
plt.ylabel("alguns numeros legais")

class Sensores(Screen):
    pass

class Grafico(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        self.add_widget(box)

class Menu(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file('sensor.kv')

class sensor(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sensor().run()

KV LANG
#:kivy 1.9.1

Menu:
    Sensores:
    Grafico:
        name: 'grafico'

<Sensores>
    name: 'sensores'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Sensor 01"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'grafico'

<Grafico>
    name: 'grafico'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code. First, in your `kv` file the `Button` action is incorrect:

```
    Button:
        text: "Sensor 01"
        on_release:
            root.Grafico()
```

If the `Button` is intended to switch to the other screen, it should be:

```
    Button:
        text: "Sensor 01"
        on_release:
            root.manager.current='grafico'
```

Second, in your `Grafico` class you have a `build()` method that is never called. If you change that from:

```
class Grafico(Screen):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box
```

to:

```
class Grafico(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        self.add_widget(box)
```

I think you will get the desired result. The key is that the `on_enter()` method is called when the `Grafico` `Screen` is displayed. The method is your code, but with a `self.add_widget(box)` added in order to add the `box` to the screen. See the [Screen Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) for more info.